# Vanilla JavaScript: Scroll to Top of Page

Tags: javascript, scrolltop

I may have missed something, but I cannot get `window.scrollTo(0,0)` to move to the top of the page.

I am implementing a sticky `aside` which works well enough. It uses `.getBoundingClientRect()` to get the initial position.

However, if the page is partly scrolled, and I refresh the page, it reads the position wrongly, and is positioned in the wrong place.

I though I would fix this by executing `window.scrollTo(0,0)` at the beginning, so that the page is at the top, and the `aside` is in the right position.

When I run the code, `window.scrollTo(0,0)` doesn’t seem to make any difference.

What is the correct way to get the reloaded window to start at the top?

I have tested it on Firefox on the Mac. Chrome and Safari gives a similar behaviour.

Please, no jQuery.

Comment: i'd suggest renaming `newly refreshed window` to `reloaded window` to avoid confusion.
as a matter of fact: if you scrolled down and reloaded the page, the browser will try its best to scroll you back to where you were before to ensure a good user experience.

Comment: Have you tried waiting for page load before scrollTo? Try using `window.onload`

Comment: If I remember correctly, it has to be called at the element you want to scroll, therefore the body element.

Comment: Are you sure that the window is the element scrolling? Also are you sure the window is scrolled at the time you are calling scrollTo?

Comment: maybe you could add an id="scroolToTop" on top of the page and then have "on load" 
    window.location.href="#scroolToTop";

Comment: @GottZ Done. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: It would be much better to just fix your sticky element instead of forcing the user to the top of the page.

Comment: @Nit How would you do that?

Comment: @TKoL That did it for me. Could you write that up as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: I see that somebody has voted to close this question and somebody has down voted it. No explanation, of course.

Comment: @Manngo You're asking people to fix your code without actually showing most of your code.

Comment: @Nit No, I’m quite capable of fixing my code. I asked why `window.scroll` was not working when I refreshed the page, and the correct answer was that I should wait until the page finished loading. Thanks for your contribution, though.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have you tried waiting for page load before scrollTo? Try using window.onload

```
window.onload = function(){
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Going to top of the page with a scroll effect is a bit more easier in javascript now with:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scroll

```
window.scroll({
 top: 0, 
 left: 0, 
 behavior: 'smooth' 
});
```

CAUTION

I just checked the mozilla doc right now while updating my answer and I believe it has been updated. Right now the method is window.scroll(x-coord, y-coord) and does not mention or show examples that use the object parameter where you can set the behavior to smooth. I just tried the code and it still works in chrome and firefox and the object parameter is still in the spec.

Or in Vanilla you can use window.onload event with scrollTo(x,y) function

```
window.onload = function(){
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
}
```