# Native javascript scroll top to bottom loop

Tags: javascript

I'd like to create two functions without using jQuery to scroll from top to bottom and bottom to top with a timeout.

**My code using jQuery (it works) :**

```
function scrollToTop() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, {
      duration: 10000,
      complete: function() {
        scrollToBottom();
      }
    });
  }, 10000);
}

function scrollToBottom() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, {
      duration: 10000,
      complete: function() {
        scrollToTop();
      }
    });
  }, 10000);
}

scrollToBottom();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vanilla JavaScript: Scroll to Top of Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46234629/vanilla-javascript-scroll-to-top-of-page)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```js
// top
setTimeout(() => window.scrollTo(0,0), 1000);

// bottom
setTimeout(() => window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight), 1000);
```

Comment: With this code I don't have an animation from top to bottom and when the scroll is setted to bottom I want to scroll to top. I'd like to create a loop from top to bottom and bottom to top.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `scroll` method, it's a native method and also has a option for different behavior.

```js
function scrollToTop() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    window.scroll({
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      behavior: 'smooth'
    });
  }, 10000);
}

function scrollToBottom() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    window.scroll({
      top: 1000,
      left: 0,
      behavior: 'smooth'
    });
  }, 10000);
}
```